# Create Action w/ Redux Toolkit; Passing in A Payload

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga, payload

I'm currently working on the sign in component portion of my app. It requires the user to sign in with their email and password. It has firebase incoporated on the back end. I've been using redux toolkit for a bulk of the app. However, I'm having trouble with createAction and trying to pass the payload in sucessfully. I also wanted to note that i'm doing the async actions via sagas. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I provided the error in the console log:

```
export const emailSignInStart = createAction(
  "user/EmailSignInStart",
  ({ email, password }) => ({
    payload: {
      email,
      password
    }
  })
);
```

```
export function* getSnapShotFromUserAuth(userAuth, additionalDetails) {
  try {
    const userSnapshot = yield call(
      createUserDocumentFromAuth,
      userAuth,
      additionalDetails
    );
    yield put(signInSuccess({ id: userSnapshot.id, ...userSnapshot.data() }));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signInFailure(error));
  }
}
```

```
export function* EmailSignIn({ payload: { email, password } }) {
  try {
    const { user } = yield call(
      signInAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword,
      email,
      password
    );
    yield call(getSnapShotFromUserAuth, user);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signInFailure(error));
  }
}
```

Result in console:

```
payload
: 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user') at eval (https://pyluef.csb.app/src/sagas/user/user.saga.js:67:29) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at next (https://pyluef.csb.app/node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1161:27) at currCb (https://pyluef.csb.app/node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1255:7)
message
: 
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')"
stack
: 
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')\n    at eval (https://pyluef.csb.app/src/sagas/user/user.saga.js:67:29)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at next (https://pyluef.csb.app/node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1161:27)\n    at currCb (https://pyluef.csb.app/node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1255:7)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
type
: 
"user/signInFailure"
@@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION
: 
true
```

**The code I used without using Redux toolkit. It worked this way:**

```
export const USER_ACTION_TYPES = {

  EMAIL_SIGN_IN_START: "user/EMAIL_SIGN_IN_START"
};
```

```
export const createAction = (type, payload) => ({ type, payload });
```

```
export const emailSignInStart = (email, password) =>
  createAction(USER_ACTION_TYPES.EMAIL_SIGN_IN_START, { email, password });
```

Comment: If the user came back as undefined then you might want to follow the call stack back out possibly all the way back to the backend API to see what the server is returning. Do you have access to the backend server to see how it processes this authentication request? In the meantime, please [edit] the post to include a [mcve]. Images of code are not acceptable as they are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and they are not copy/pasteable.

Comment: I used firebase on the backend. I edited the post and provided the code that worked without using redux toolkit.  It took a lot more steps.  I'm still unsure why it didn't work with the built-in action creator from toolkit.

Comment: FWIW I don't think the error is saying that any action payload is undefined, but that the code can't destructure `user` from undefined. The only place in code you shared I see any `user` property referenced is in the saga from the `yield call(signInAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword, email, password)` call.

Comment: Hi. Well once we pass in the password and email into the signInAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword method from firebase it sends us back a user credentials object which has a user object as a prop.

Comment: Are you saying the `user` object/reference is defined and has the value you expect from `const { user } = yield call(signInAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword, email, password);`? What exact line of code is causing the error? Can you include a better and more complete code stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using @redux/toolkit, you don't need to create action - it will create them for you. Import action `emailSignInStart` from user reducer file and then simply put your payload in one piece as an object when dispatching the action like that:

```
dispatch(emailSignInStart({email, password}));
```